# record order in T-sql changing with statistics update

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, table-statistics

I am facing an issue with the record order in the given query.

```
SELECT 
EA.eaid, --int , PK of table1
EA.an, --varchar(max)
EA.dn, --varchar(max)
ET.etid, --int
ET.st --int
FROM dbo.table1 EA
JOIN dbo.table2 ET ON EA.etid = ET.etid
JOIN @tableAttribute TA ON EA.eaid = TA.id -- TA.id is int and is not a PK
ORDER BY ET.st
```

The value of ET.st column is same for all records in the given scenario.

The order of records given by the query is changing randomly on updating statistics.
Sometimes it is in order of EA.eaid and sometimes in the order of TA.id.

Please provide an explanation for such a behaviour.How is the statistics affecting the ordering here?

I am using sql server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

The order of rows returned from a database query is undefined unless specified by an `ORDER BY` clause. Since you are only ordering by `ET.st` and all values of this column are the same, the results will be returned in a non-deterministic order (based on the plan determined by the optimizer and the order of indexes used). Updating index statistics allows the query optimizer to choose the best (usually the most deterministic) indexes; it is likely that the query plan has changed as a result which is causing a different ordering to come out.

It sounds to me like you want to order by something other than `ET.st`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how indexes and plan is used by optimizer for ordering?How statistics is used in this case?

Comment: @MukulSinghSaini I have added a sentence to explain, but the key is they *aren't ordered*. They are just coming out in the order the matching rows are discovered.

Comment: Yes,you are right, I actually wanted them in order of @tableAttribue records and have already figured out how to do it. But I wanted to know how sql server orders the rows in case of a redundant order by or a missing order by specially with joins in query.

Comment: Have a read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx?Redirected=true